# Checking for readonly in Geb

Tags: groovy, automation, automated-tests, spock, geb

I'm trying to write a test in Geb that has a bunch of different text fields. The scenario is essentially that there are five or six html inputs and the user should only be allowed to type in one of them at a time. That is, if the first textbox has a value, the rest of the boxes should be immutable.

Instead of the element having an input type="disabled", they have an attribute (I'm assuming it's an attribute?) of readonly.

Here is a generic example:

```
<input aria-labelledby="Date Input Value 1" id="Date Input 1" name="Date Input 1" class="input-small DateOrEmpty dateInput" value="" style="display: inline-block;" readonly="">
```

I've tried

```
${"input", id: "Date Input 1"}.@readonly
```

as well as

```
${"input", id: "Date Input 1"}.has("readonly")
```

and I haven't had much luck..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having to deal with the fact that even an empty `readonly` attribute will cause the element to be read only but `$("input[id='Date Input 1']").@readonly` evaluates to a *falsey* value (as `@readonly` returns the value of the attribute which is an empty string in your case) why not turn the navigator into an instance of [`FormElement` module](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#form-element) and use the `isReadOnly()` property method it provides?

```
$("input[id='Date Input 1']").module(FormElement).readOnly
```

**EDIT**
As pointed out by kriegaex, `$("input[id='Date Input 1']").@readonly` actually evaluates to a *truthy* value (because WebDriver always returns a string which contains `true` when obtaining the value of `readonly` attribute as long as the attribute is defined on the element and regardless of the actual value of that attribute).

The above means that:

```
$("input[id='Date Input 1']").module(FormElement).readOnly
```

and:

```
$("input[id='Date Input 1']").@readonly
```

are equivalent in that they evaluate to a *truthy* value.

Comment: While this is a great answer and of course more elegant than mine, the statement that `$("input[id='Date Input 1']").@readonly` should evaluate to `false` in case the attribute is `readonly=""` is incorrect. I had assumed that too, but when testing it I found that the sheer existence of `readonly` makes it evaluate to `true` even if the value is an empty string. I even expanded my answer by an example for it just now.

Comment: You are right, kriegaex. I did some testing as well and it looks like WebDriver always returns a string which contains `true` when obtaining the value of `readonly` attribute as long as the attribute is defined on the element and regardless of the actual value of that attribute. This means that your answer is also correct.

Comment: Thanks for investigating. The only mystery remaining is, why @PackersFan said my solution did not work for him, but yours obviously did because he accepted the answer. I think he just made a mistake when trying my solution. Anyway, SO is about learning, and we all learned something here. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems here:

- You use HTML IDs with inline spaces. This are actually not legal names and make it more difficult to write simple CSS selectors like `#my-id` for them.
- Geb syntax for selectors uses parentheses, not curly braces. Curly braces are used for closures, which are a completely different kind of beast.
- Please note that according to [HTML specification](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) the `readonly` attribute is boolean and always true if it exists at all, i.e. usually you do not write `readonly="something"` but just `readonly`. Even if you write `readonly="false"` it will evaluate to true because its value is ignored, only its existence is checked.

So if you have this HTML code:

```xml
<input id="Date Input 1" readonly>
<input id="Date Input 2">
<input id="date-input-3" readonly="false">
<input id="date-input-4">
<input id="date-input-5" readonly="">
```

You can write these selectors in your Geb test (please note how not using spaces in IDs makes the selectors simpler):

```java
$("input[id='Date Input 1']").@readonly
!$("input[id='Date Input 2']").@readonly
$("input#date-input-3").@readonly
!$("input#date-input-4").@readonly
$("input#date-input-5").@readonly
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I realized after your note that I used {} instead of () in my post, but in my code I am in fact using ()... I also know that spaces in IDs are bad, but, it's a legacy application that I don't have the power to make the change to given my constraints...

This is the error message I received after trying @readonly 

`Condition not satisfied:

page.input1Example.@readonly
|               |                            |
|               |                            ""
|               page -> input1Example: geb.navigator.NonEmptyNavigator
java.package.page`

Comment: You must be making a mistake. My solution is correct and tested. Unless you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) proving otherwise, I am assuming the problem sits in front of the computer. ;-) With the information I have from you I cannot say more.